# Change padding of section depending on number of posts returned

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

I have a posts feed in Elementor where the posts stack vertically and partially overlap the next section below it.  I need to change the bottom padding of the posts section depending on the number of posts returned so they are in line with the right background and look correct.  I am trying to figure out how we can get the number of the posts using the feed's selector ID and then change the bottom padding depending on how many posts there are.

Any idea how to achieve this?

So something like:

```
$feed = getElementById('feedID');
$posts = get_posts($feed);
$count = count($posts);

if ($count === 1) {
   $feed.css('padding-bottom', 100 . 'px');
} elseif ($count === 2) {
   $feed.css('padding-bottom', 200 . 'px');
}
```

Comment: If you want to do it using client-side JavaScript, you should probably be able to simply count the child elements of the container these posts are in. `document.querySelector('#container > div').length`, modified to match the specifics of your HTML structure.

Comment: why not just apply class to your container ?